# Firefox media resource could not be decoded

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, mime-types, mime

I only have this problem when using Firefox.

First let me show you my stream response from the server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key
Access-Control-Allow-Method GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Connection keep-alive
Date Thu, 04 Jun 2015 10:44:51 GMT
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Powered-By Express
```

And my request header:

```
Accept video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Host localhost:8105
Range bytes=0-
Referer http://localhost/myProject/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
```

Then when I call this request i get:

```
Media resource (link) could not be decoded
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and it turned out I had to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and then restart Firefox and it now works like clockwork.

Footnote: I had previously tried to install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` and restart Firefox, but this had no effect.

Comment: This did not have any effect for me.